# Checking the structure of a string using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I don't have a deep knowledge of regular expressions (I just learned it today). I have a website and I want to ask how I create a 6 digit security code either in the form of:

```
1.  LNLNLN       
or    
2.  NLNLNL

Where L = Letter and N = Number
```

I am not sure of the best way to do this, but I have seen people using `preg_match()` to validate data. I found that using this regular expression works:

```
^[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9]|^[0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z]
```

but this seems pretty long. I wonder if there is any way that I can check this more easily?
 Thank you

Comment: hope you know this is not particularly 'secure' of course it may be fine depending on how its uses

Comment: But isn't there quite a lot of possible combinations in this secure code? I am still pretty new in making online application.

Comment: the issue is, what are you using it for? enforcing must be letter must be digit fixed length of 6 decreases the security (gueesability) over could be either of any length

Comment: If users forget their username or password, they can either use their original registered email or this secure code to recover username or password.

Comment: so its really another password, so i wouldn't do this, i would just use the email method. if i forgot my password, do you think i remembered this code?

Comment: maybe enforce a minimum  length, maybe enforce must have at least 1 digit, but dont think this is really increaseing security

Comment: I see. Maybe I should just ignore the secure code in my website. But at least I learned something from your guys. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [repetition](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php)

```
^([a-zA-Z][0-9]){3}|^([0-9][a-zA-Z]){3}
```

Then [escape sequence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) \d

```
^([a-zA-Z]\d){3}|^(\d[a-zA-Z]){3}
```

With i [option](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.internal-options.php#regexp.reference.internal-options) you can write even this.

```
^([a-z]\d){3}|^(\d[a-z]){3}

preg_match('/^([a-z]\d){3}|^(\d[a-z]){3}/i', $string)
```

Comment: the use of `\d` would make it a tiny bit smaller

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code is so much simpler than mine. I will keep learning how to make simpler code.

Comment: @Dagon Oh you efficiency-seeking soul! :)